# Is Save Using SESSION in Login System

Tags: php, session, session-variables

im create login system with session, but i want to know is that save using session in login & Admin Page?

my login code

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
 {  
      header("location: index.php");
      exit();
 }

if(isset ($_POST["login"])) 
           {  
                $query = "SELECT * FROM jy_users WHERE jy_username = :username AND jy_password = md5(:password)";  
                $statement = $db->prepare($query);  
                $statement->execute(  
                     array(  
                          'username'     =>     htmlentities($_POST["username"]),  
                          'password'     =>     htmlentities($_POST["password"])  
                     )  
                );
                $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                if($count > 0)  
                {  
                     $_SESSION["username"] = htmlentities($_POST["username"]);
                     while ($auth = $statement->fetch()) {
                      $_SESSION["auth"] = htmlentities($auth['jy_auth']); 
                     }
                     header("location: index.php");  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     $message = '<label>Wrong Password or Username.</label>';  
                }  
           }   
 }
```

for example in `admin.php` im create a simple code like this.

```
session_start();

if(empty($_SESSION["username"]))  
 {
      header("location: login.php");
      exit();
 } /* code for admin page bellow */
```

`session_destroy()` im set it in `logout.php`

```
session_start();  
 session_destroy();
```

is that posible users fake session variable for `$_SESSION["username"]`

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible for users to add their own session variables, so that's okay. However, md5 is not a reliable algorithm to use for hashing passwords.